# Can I have one page for all profiles?

Tags: php

The idea is to click on the name of an employee and go to a page called profile.php. This page will always be profile.php but will output different information depending on which employees name is selected. This is the code I have so far.

```
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, role, branch FROM users WHERE role='maintenence' ORDER BY firstname, lastname ASC;";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<a href='profile.php'><tr><td class='col-s-4'>" . "<a href='profile.php'>" . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . "</td><td class='col-s-4'>" . $row['role'] . "</td><td class='col-s-4'>" . $row['branch'] . "</td></tr></a>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

It is doing exactly what I want it to do at the moment. But if the above is possible, how can I store a variable of the employee chosen (employee id) so I can use that variable to output information on profile.php. Thank you.

Comment: you pass a unique param to profile.php and then pick it up with `$_GET['id']` etc, then query the db based upon the id, basic stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you use a parameter from a request parameter ($_GET or $_POST or $_REQUEST) or something from the session to seed your query.

```
"<a href='profile.php?id=" . $row['employee_id'] . "'>" . $row['firstname'] . "</a>"
```

In profile.php, you can access the request parameter as `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question, You can use AJAX here to dynamically change content without refreshing the page...If you're not familiar with AJAX requests, check out some [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), it is easy to implement and perfect if you need to load content dynamically. i.e. Loading details like employee salary etc based on whichever employee is selected...This can be implemented mainly using javascript/jquery and AJAX.